# how do I finish this program? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, crossrider

The code below belongs to a crossrider extension I am currently attempting to develop that hopefully will sync bookmarks across browsers. This file is currently the background.js file it will first retrieve a snapshot of the bookmarks file from the local database then compare that to the current list of bookmarks and if there are any differences (either additions to the bookmarks list or subtractions) they will be be returned with the getChanges() function and then sent to the server, finally the script updates the snapshot and waits 30 seconds before restarting the process. I dont really know how to make the getChanges() function. It needs to return presumably a json object indicating both the additions and subtractions (both their titles and urls). If someone could write the code for the function that would be great. Thanks

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
// Poll every 30 seconds
setInterval(function() {
  appAPI.db.async.get('prevBookmarks', function(value) {
  // Load or initialize previous bookmarks list
  var prevBookmarks = (value) ? value : {};

  // Get current bookmarks
  appAPI.bookmarks.getTree(function(nodes) {
    // Save bookmark list for next comparison
    appAPI.db.async.set('prevBookmarks', nodes);

    // In your getChanges functions, traverse the bookmark trees collating
    // changes and then post then to your API server using appAPI.request
    var changes = getChanges(prevBookmarks, nodes);
    appAPI.request.post({
      url: http://yourAPIserver.com,
      postData: changes,
      contentType: 'application/json'
    });
  });
});
}, 30 * 1000);
});
```

Comment: Sorry friend, that is not what StackOverflow is here for.  You are the author of your code, not the community.  You have to at least try to do it yourself, post what you tried and provide code snippets.  A one-liner to a function that doesn't exist isn't enough.  Give it a try, post your `getChanges` function and then ask for help.  There are plenty of people here who will be happy to do so. (For the record, I did not down-vote your question.)

Comment: well the problem is that i am new to coding and even newer to javascript and i really dont know where to even start with this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you've got jQuery as one of your tags, so try this link: [Compare 2 arrays which returns difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/jquery-compare-2-arrays-return-difference).

It returns the differences between two arrays.  You'll have to perform this twice for what you're doing, once to figure out what is in `current` that is not in `previous` and vice versa.  I don't know what properties are contained in your bookmarks so this simple example might not exactly suit your needs, but it might point you in the right direction.

Good luck and welcome to JavaScript!