# filtering an array of objects using an array without nested loops js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been trying to figure out the cleanest way to filter an array of objects without using nested loops.
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317954/passing-array-to-filter-method) using `.filter` function about filtering an array using another array but I failed on figuring out how to actually access the right key within the object in array of objects using the same pattern
Given the next following array of objects:

```
[ { technology: 'CHARACTER', score: -1 },
{ technology: 'PRESSURE_RELIEF', score: 2 },
{ technology: 'SUPPORT', score: 3 },
{ technology: 'MOTION_ISOLATION', score: 2 },
{ technology: 'TEMPERATURE_MANAGEMENT', score: -1 },
{ technology: 'COMFORT', score: 2 } ]
```

I want to use the following array to filter the ones I don't need:

```
[CHARACTER, MOTION_ISOLATION, TEMPERATURE_MANAGEMENT]
```

Is it even possible to access it without using a nested loop? I'm also open to suggestions if not possible.

Comment: You can do it without nested loops by using something other than an array to hold the keys to search for. If you use an array, then *something* is going to have to iterate through the array in order to find a match (or determine there's no match).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) like so

```js
var condition = ['CHARACTER', 'MOTION_ISOLATION', 'TEMPERATURE_MANAGEMENT'];

var data = [ 
  { technology: 'CHARACTER', score: -1 },
  { technology: 'PRESSURE_RELIEF', score: 2 },
  { technology: 'SUPPORT', score: 3 },
  { technology: 'MOTION_ISOLATION', score: 2 },
  { technology: 'TEMPERATURE_MANAGEMENT', score: -1 },
  { technology: 'COMFORT', score: 2 } 
];

var result = data.filter(function (el) {
  return condition.indexOf(el.technology) < 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Thanks so much. Will .filter return me a new object without the elements I'm filtering? And pls correct me if I'm wrong but I thought .filter when passing a callback will return a boolean.

Comment: @mauricioSanchez no, `.filter()` returns a filtered array (a **new** array). And note also that `.indexOf()` is internally looping over the "condition" array.

Comment: Makes sense! This is exactly what I needed it!