# Javascript: filter an array of objects using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of Objects:

```
[
    {id: 1, thing_id: 2},
    {id: 1, thing_id: 3},
    {id: 1, thing_id: 4}
]
```

and I want to filter that using an array of thing_ids:

```
[2,3]
```

I did look at [filtering an array of objects using an array without nested loops js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480627/filtering-an-array-of-objects-using-an-array-without-nested-loops-js) but it doesn't seem to work.

Clearly I need to use `.filter` somehow?

Mick

Comment: `var newArray = arr.filter(a => thing_ids.includes(a.id))`

Comment: Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) examples

Comment: You can use underscore library for javascript (_.filter function ) Example :var array= [{id : 1 , id_thinng:2}, {id :1 , id_thing:3} ,{id:1, id_thing:4}];
                var newArray = _.filter(array, function(test){
                    return test.id_thing == 2 || test.id_thing == 3 ;
                });
                console.log(newArray);

Comment: @HousseinZouari, Why do you need a library when things can be achieved using vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like the following way:

```js
var arr1 = [{ id:1, thing_id: 2},
{ id: 1, thing_id: 3},
{ id: 1, thing_id: 4}];

var arr2 = [2,3]

var res = arr1.filter(i => arr2.includes(i.thing_id))
console.log(res);
```