# Javascript/Jquery- new array from existing two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays

```
 var a= $("#update-select1").val();  // gives value 1,2,4
 var b= $("#update-select2").val();  // 1,2,5
```

I want two different arrays from the above two arrays.

```
//array has the values which is in  `b` but not in `a`
var c = [5]

//another array has value in `a` but not in `b`
var d =[4]
```

Comment: You need to explain this a lot better, you're probably looking for `concat()`, but who knows ?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference) helps you out

Comment: `val()` doesn't even return arrays ?

Comment: @adeneo for SELECT with attribute multiple, jquery `val()` returns array. I was thinking the same...

Comment: @A.Wolff - It would, but plain javascript wouldn't, one of those convenient things added by jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter` this way:

```
var c = [1,2,5]
          .filter(function(a){return this.indexOf(a) === -1},[1,2,4]); //=> [5]
var d = [1,2,4]
          .filter(function(a){return this.indexOf(a) === -1},[1,2,5]); //=> [4]
```

Or:

```
function notIn(a){
   return this.indexOf(a) === -1;
}
var a = [1,2,4]
   ,b = [1,2,5]
   ,c = b.filter(notIn,a)
   ,d = a.filter(notIn,b);
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: TypeError: a.filter is not a function.filter(function(a){return this.indexOf(a) === -1},[1,2,5]); //=> [4]

Comment: @monda: in that case you probably need the shim/Polyfill from the 'See also' link. Idem for `indexOf`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `grep()` method

```
var a1 = [1, 2, 4];
var a2 = [1, 2, 5];
var difference = $.grep(a1, function (x) {
                     return $.inArray(x, a2) < 0
                 });

alert(" the difference is " + difference);​
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/u9xES/428/)**

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is an old question, but I thought I would share this
>   little trick.

```
var diff = $(old_array).not(new_array).get();
```

> diff now contains what was in old_array that is not in new_array

Found this on  [Compare 2 arrays which returns difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/jquery-compare-2-arrays-return-difference)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var a= [1,2,4];
var b= [1,2,5];

 var c = [];
 jQuery.each(b,function(k,v){
    if(a.indexOf(v) < 0){
        c.push(v);
    }
 })
 console.log(c);//[5]

 var d = [];
 jQuery.each(a,function(k,v){
    if(b.indexOf(v) < 0){
        d.push(v);
    }
 })
 console.log(d);//[4]
```