# I want to compare 2 object arrays in JS

Tags: javascript

I have 2 object arrays a1 and a2 with ID and Name properties.
1. I want to compare a1 and a2 and delete whatever is there in a1 which is not in 
   a2.
2. Add whatever is in a2 but not in a1.

I want to store the delete and add results in 2 different arrays.

Comment: This post doesn't show any research or effort on your part to solve your issues.

Comment: no research effort, -1 also @Oen44 I don't think this is the way.. you will see this for yourself of course, I guess :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Even if someone would want to do this work for you, your description is too vague. Ex: What decides if two objects are equal?

Comment: Ozgar - I have mentioned 2 elements Id and Name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to manage your array.

```
var a1_filtered = a.filter(function(current_a){
    return b.filter(function(current_b){
       [your code...]  
});
```

You can find the full example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21988185/3345789

don't forget to search please :)