# Change options only if something changed via AJAX Response

Tags: ajax, symfony, response

I need your help concerning AJAX Responses with Symfony. On my page I have select options and want only refresh them, if anything in DB has changed. Now I'm loading every five seconds and checking if data count is different. But on the other hand users could also edit/rename old options. If I only check the count it's not possible to refresh the list. So how can I check if old response different than the new one?

Thanks in advance!! 
(My code in JS as follows)

```
let Routing = require('../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router')
let Routes = require('./js_routes')

Routing.setRoutingData(Routes)

let select_options = document.getElementById("person_names")

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("entity=Person&action=new") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("entity=Person&action=edit") > -1){
        let firstRequest = true;
        let responseOld
        window.setInterval(function () {
            new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
                let url = Routing.generate('getNewPersonList')
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                xhr.open('GET', url)

                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
                xhr.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

                    if (this.status === 200 && this.statusText === "OK"){
                        resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
                    } else {
                        reject(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
                    }
                })
                xhr.send()
            })

                .then((response) => {
                    debugger;
                    if (firstRequest){
                        responseOld = response
                        firstRequest = false
                        // document.cookie = "Names=" + response + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/refreshNames";
                        console.log("first")
                    }
                    if (select_options.length !== response.length) {
                        console.log(select_options)
                        console.log(response)

                        // Drop old options
                        select_options.length = 0

                        // Fill it with new names
                        for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                            let $option_element = document.createElement('option')
                            $option_element.value = response[index].id
                            $option_element.text = response[index].name
                            select_options.appendChild($option_element)
                        }
                    }
                })

                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
    }, 5000)
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe store the response in a variable and compare new response on each call using array comparison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript/21988185

Comment: Hmm.. I will try it now. What about to do via some cookies?