# How to compare 2 arrays of object with different length?

Tags: javascript

I work on an angular application and I have to compare 2 arrays of object :

```
ar1 = [{id: 2, itemId: 1},
    {id: 5, itemId: 3},
    {id: 18,itemId: 13},
    {id: 16,itemId: 14}]

ar2 = [{id: 13, itemId: 1},
    {id: 12, itemId: 14}]
```

I try to do something like this:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < this.ar1.length ; i++){
    if(this.ar2[i] != undefined){
        if(this.ar1[i].itemId == this.ar2[i].itemId){
            console.log("in and ==itemId",this.ar2[i])
        }
        else{
            console.log("in and !=itemId",this.ar1[i])
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("undefined",this.ar1[i])
    }
}
```

It's return me that :

```
in and ==itemId {id: 13, itemId: 1}
in and !=itemId {id: 5, itemId: 3}
undefined {id: 18, itemId: 13}
undefined {id: 16, itemId: 14}
```

I want a function which can say me which object is in the 2 arrays and which object is not in the 2 arrays.

It's not a duplicate cause I don't want to see difference between 2 arrays of object but see if the itemId if the same and get the object with the same itemId.

Comment: You just want to check whether both are equal or not?

Comment: do you want to compare both id and itemId or just id only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to check if the itemId is the same.

Comment: please check below answer you need to use the foreach

Comment: I have create a stackblitz to solve your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmhktk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have t iterate over both array and find it id of arr1 is present in arr2 or not

```js
ar1 = [{
    id: 2,
    itemId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    itemId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    itemId: 13
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    itemId: 14
  }
]

ar2 = [{
    id: 13,
    itemId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    itemId: 14
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < this.ar1.length; i++) {
  id = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < this.ar2.length; j++) {
    if (this.ar1[i].itemId == this.ar2[j].itemId) {
      id = true
      data = this.ar2[j];
    }

  }
  if (id) {
    console.log("in and ==itemId", data)
  } else {
    console.log("in and !=itemId", this.ar1[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate over both arrays so you can compare all of the values of `ar1` with all of the values of `ar2`.

Here is the basic logic to run the code snippet:

```js
let ar1 = [
  {id: 2, itemId: 1},
  {id: 5, itemId: 3},
  {id: 18,itemId: 13},
  {id: 16,itemId: 14}
];

let ar2 = [
  {id: 13, itemId: 1},
  {id: 12, itemId: 14}
];

for (let x = 0; x < ar1.length; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < ar2.length; y++) {
    if (ar1[x].itemId === ar2[y].itemId) {
      console.log("id: " + ar1[x].id + ", itemId: " + ar1[x].itemId + " = id: " + ar2[y].id + ", itemId: " + ar2[y].itemId);
    }
  }
}
```

You can simplify this further by using `forEach` instead of traditional for loops. You can also change the `console.log` logic to fit whatever data you are expecting to output.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

```js
ar1 = [
  {id: 2, itemId: 1},
  {id: 5, itemId: 3},
  {id: 18, itemId: 13},
  {id: 16, itemId: 14},
];

ar2 = [
  {id: 2, itemId: 1},
  {id: 5, itemId: 25},
  {id: 18, itemId: 13},
  {id: 22, itemId: 14},
];

intersection = ar1.filter(x => ar2.map(y => y.itemId).includes(x.itemId));
console.log(intersection);
```

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using traditional `for` use `foreach` which will traverse every element from the array and check with another element in the array.

**your.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  ar1 = [{ id: 2, itemId: 1 },
  { id: 5, itemId: 3 },
  { id: 18, itemId: 13 },
  { id: 16, itemId: 14 }]

  ar2 = [{ id: 13, itemId: 1 },
  { id: 12, itemId: 14 }]

 constructor () {
   this.compareArray()
 }


  compareArray() {

    this.ar1.forEach( array1Ttem => {

      this.ar2.forEach( array2Item => {

         if(array1Ttem.itemId == array2Item.itemId){
            console.log("in and ==itemId",array1Ttem);
        }
        else{
            console.log("in and !=itemId",array1Ttem);
        }

      })
    })
  }
}
```

**[Solution on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmhktk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `ar1` and use `findIndex` to check if there exist an object on `ar2` which has same `itemId`

```js
let ar1 = [{
    id: 2,
    itemId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    itemId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    itemId: 13
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    itemId: 14
  }
]

let ar2 = [{
    id: 13,
    itemId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    itemId: 14
  }
]

ar1.forEach(function(item) {

  let findIndexInar2 = ar2.findIndex(function(elem) {
    return item.itemId === elem.itemId;
  })

  if (findIndexInar2 !== -1) {
    console.log('itemId present in ar2')

  } else {
    console.log('itemId not present in ar2')

  }



})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like this :

```
const ar1 = [
  { id: 2, itemId: 1 },
  { id: 5, itemId: 3 },
  { id: 18, itemId: 13 },
  { id: 16, itemId: 14 },
]

const ar2 = [{ id: 13, itemId: 1 }, { id: 12, itemId: 14 }]
const inTwoArray = []
const notInTwoArray = []
ar1.forEach(el => {
  if (ar2.find(el1 => el1.itemId === el.itemId)) {
    inTwoArray.push(el)
  } else {
    notInTwoArray.push(el)
  }
})

console.log(inTwoArray)
console.log(notInTwoArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet will help you to find where your `itemId` is common -

```js
let ar1 = [{ id: 2, itemId: 1 },
    { id: 5, itemId: 3 },
    { id: 18, itemId: 13 },
    { id: 16, itemId: 14 }
];

let ar2 = [{ id: 13, itemId: 1 },
    { id: 12, itemId: 14 }
];

let checkCommonElements = function(arr1, arr2) {
    arr1.forEach((object1, index1) => {
     let flag = false;
        arr2.forEach((object2, index2) => {
            if (object1.itemId === object2.itemId) {
             flag = true;
                console.log("Item present in ar2: ", JSON.stringify(object1));
            }
        });
        if(!flag) {
            console.log("Item not in ar2: ", JSON.stringify(object1));
        }
    });
}

checkCommonElements(ar1, ar2);
```