# Left join with lowdb

Tags: javascript, sql, database

I have two "tables"/arrays, user and order, in my JSON database.
It looks like this :

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "test"
    }
  ],
  "order": [
    {
      "user_id": "1",
      "date_order": "2018-01-01",
      "end_order": "2018-01-05"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "2",
      "date_order": "2018-02-01",
      "end_order": "2018-02-05"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve all the users who haven't an order associated to them.
So in this case, only the user #3.
Is there a specific function to do a left join ? I read the README but I can't figure out how to "join" two "tables".
Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` on user array and use `find()` on `order` array to check if there is any object with `user_id` equal to id of obj in user array.

```js
const obj = { "user": [ { "id": "1", "name": "test" }, { "id": "2", "name": "test" }, { "id": "3", "name": "test" } ], "order": [ { "user_id": "1", "date_order": "2018-01-01", "end_order": "2018-01-05" }, { "user_id": "2", "date_order": "2018-02-01", "end_order": "2018-02-05" } ] }

const res = obj.user.filter(x => !obj.order.find(a => a.user_id === x.id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`lowdb` does not have a `join` functionality at this moment. `user` and `order` are treated as `databases` rather than `tables`.

You may create your orders inside your `user db` if you would like to make queries with `lowdb` syntax.

In the case you continue using the data structure of your question, you could do something like this:

```
const userIds = db('order').map('user_id');
const users = db('user').filter(user => !userIds.includes(user.id));
```

Note that in this case, you would be querying all your `userIds` first. This could lead to a performance issue if that number is big.