# lowdb - how to query multiple records?

Tags: javascript, lowdb

I'm using https://github.com/typicode/lowdb for a small project. I need a query which searches multiple records and returns each record it finds as an array.

For example, for a db such as:

```
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "sadohfdsf",
      "username": "user1",
      "data": "abc"
    },
    {
      "id": "tiyuykuy",
      "username": "user1",
      "data": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "id": "tryehhrt",
      "username": "user2",
      "data": "tyu"
    }
  ]
```

I'd like to query all the records for `username: "user1"` and get all the records for that user in an array.

I've tried the default:

```
const user = await db.get('records')
.find({ username: "user1" })
.value();

return user;
```

but it only finds the first record in the db.

What's the correct way to find multiple records in lowdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE**: I don't use LowDB

Judging by the docs, I think it's not possible to find multiple records in LowDB. Instead, you can use the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
// Assuming the following returns an array of your object
const users = await db.get('records')
    .value();

// We can `filter` the user(s)
const result = users.filter(
    user => user.username === 'user1' /* or any other username */
);
```

Comment: yeah seems like there is no findAll(). your solution works well!

Answer (score 2):

Use filter instead of find .

```
const users = await db('records').filter({ username: "user1" });
```

Ref: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/185
[Left join with lowdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995045/left-join-with-lowdb)

Multipe filters means use chain() as well