# How can I find the difference of arrays of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript), however every single answer doesn't work in my script, asking this was my very last resort.

I am trying to find new data uploaded to a database, this is the logic it follows:

Read data from my Mongo database store as `a` >> Pull new data from sql server, store as `b` >> filter the data and overwrite my Mongo database >> compare `a` and `b` to find new documents uploaded.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function comparer(otherArray){
  return function(current){
    return otherArray.filter(function(other){
      return other.value == current.value && other.display == current.display
    }).length == 0;
  }
}

var onlyInA = a.filter(comparer(b));
var onlyInB = b.filter(comparer(a));

result = onlyInA.concat(onlyInB);

console.log(result);
```

I obtain `a` and `b` like so:

```
a = await dbo.collection("master").find({ }, {projection:{_id: 0}}).toArray();

//upload all new data here, so b contains more objects than a

b = await dbo.collection("master").find({ }, {projection:{_id: 0}}).toArray();
```

I am expecting this to return all objects in `b` except if the objects exist in `a`, so I should see new data.

Here is a brief sample of my database;

```
a = [{
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Num": "000000",
        }]

b = [{
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Num": "000000",
        },
        {
            "Process": "Process2",
            "Num": "000107",
        }]
```

Therefore `b` contains more objects, so finding the difference should show the object containing process 2. Thanks for any help!

Comment: use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unionBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question/answer you took `comparer` from referred to properties called `display` and `value`, but *your* objects have properties `Process` and `Num`.

When you change to the correct properties, the result is as expected.

```js
var a = [{
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Num": "000000",
        }]

var b = [{
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Num": "000000",
        },
        {
            "Process": "Process2",
            "Num": "000107",
        }]
        
function comparer(otherArray){
  return function(current){
    return otherArray.filter(function(other){
      return other.Process == current.Process && other.Num == current.Num
    }).length == 0;
  }
}

var onlyInA = a.filter(comparer(b));
var onlyInB = b.filter(comparer(a));

result = onlyInA.concat(onlyInB);

console.log(result);
```