# Difference between two arrays of objects with matching name (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to return difference between two arrays of objects using `array.filter()` and `array.some()` but I can't get the desired result. Maybe I need to have the same attributes **id** and **name** into this two arrays.

Here my two arrays

```js
let array1 = [
  { 'id': 1, 'name': 'apple' }, 
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'blueberry' }
]

let array2 = [
  { 'id': 1, 'name': 'apple' }, 
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'blueberry' }, 
  { 'name': 'banana' }
]
```

Here my code

```js
let difference = array1.filter(x => !array2.some(y => x.name === y.name))

console.log(difference) // empty but I want this -> [{ 'name': banana }]
```

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: The "problem" is the different `length` between them.

Comment: You are taking difference of array2 from array1, the result would be empty. For desired result, please take difference of array1 from array2.

Comment: let difference = array2.filter(x => !array1.some(y => x.name === y.name))