# Get the difference between two arrays

Tags: javascript

I need to get only the difference between two arrays

I tried:

```
let arr1 = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "EID_Floss",
        "name": "Floss",
        "te": "dd"
    }]
}
let arr2 = {
    "data": [{
        "id": "EID_Floss",
        "name": "Floss"
    }]
}
JSON.stringify(arr2.data.filter((x) => !arr1.data.includes(x)))
```

Result:

```
[{
    "id": "EID_Floss",
    "name": "Floss"
}]
```

How to get only this:

```
[{
   "te": "dd"
}]
```

Comment: Why is `arr1` not an array? What if the `data` attributes have more than one element? Please be more detailed in your question.

Comment: How do you define "difference between two arrays"? Do you mean throw out elements of one array that are not in the other?

Comment: Are you trying to take the difference of the individual objects in the array? Is this by key, or both key and value?

Comment: Do you really want the difference between two arrays? Or do you want the difference between each object in the arrays?

Comment: Note that `arr1` and `arr2` are **objects**, not arrays. Let's simplify your example to just be arrays instead of the unecessary complex nesting.

Comment: the result is [{
    "id": "EID_Floss",
    "name": "Floss"
}]

I don't need the same data I need difference between them

Comment: take a look at this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Look at this simpler example:

```
arr1 = ["foo", "bar"];
arr2 = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"];

arr3 = arr2.filter((x) => !arr1.includes(x));
console.log(arr3);
```

This does exactly what you exect and the output is:

> ["foobar"]

The problem with your example, is that the arrays in `arr1.data` and `arr2.data` contain **objects**. You are comparing the object

```
{
        "id": "EID_Floss",
        "name": "Floss",
        "te": "dd"
}
```

from `arr1` with the object

```
{
        "id": "EID_Floss",
        "name": "Floss"
}
```

from `arr2`. Since these are not equal, your filter does not remove the object from the array.

Note that this is an all or nothing operation since you are filtering the array of objects. Instead, it sounds like you want to filter the **keys** in each object. So you need to use `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` to iterate over the contents of the objects.