# how to compare two arrays and remove, update elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects like

```
a = [
            {chargeType: "Accounting Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Commission", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Processing Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Verification Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Application Fees", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Legal Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Bank Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
]
```

and

```
b = [
                {chargeType: "Accounting Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Commission", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Processing Charges", ct: 7, st: 7, it: 14},
                {chargeType: "Verification Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Application Fees", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Legal Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
]
```

1.now by comparing both arrays If any charges missing in array b then add a boolean property in array a. like in array A bank charges record is there, but it's missing in array B. so, I have to add a property to that bank charges object in array A.

2. in Array B if any record is updated those values should be copied in array A. like in array B proceesing charges record ct,st and it values are updated and those values should be updated in array A.

can anyone help how to achieve this

Comment: please add your code. what does not work?

Comment: look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

According to what's asked

> 1.now by comparing both arrays If any charges missing in array b then add a boolean property in array a. like in array A bank charges
> record is there, but it's missing in array B. so, I have to add a
> property to that bank charges object in array A.
> in Array B if any record is updated those values should be copied in array A. like in array B proceesing charges record ct,st and it
> values are updated and those values should be updated in array A.

This can be done with one line:

```
Object.assign(x,y) // x <-- what was in x, updated with what was in y
```

I'm changing one value in `a` for showing that it is updated with what comes from `b`

```js
a = [
            {chargeType: "Accounting Charges", ct: 111111111111, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Commission", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Processing Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Verification Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Application Fees", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Legal Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
            {chargeType: "Bank Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
]
b = [
                {chargeType: "Accounting Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Commission", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Processing Charges", ct: 7, st: 7, it: 14},
                {chargeType: "Verification Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Application Fees", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
                {chargeType: "Legal Charges", ct: 6, st: 6, it: 12},
]

Object.assign(a,b)

console.log(a)
```

If you want to keep `a` as it is and create a new object:

```
c = Object.assign({},a,b);
```