# filter array of objects in javascript using another array of objects by id

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 arrays of objects with ids:

```
    const oldOffers = [
  {
    _id: "1"
  },
  {
    _id: "2"
  },
  {
    _id: "3"
  }
];

const activeOffers = [
  {
    _id: "1"
  },
  {
    _id: "5"
  }
];
```

I need to have a new array with objects that are present in oldOffers but are not present in activeOffers; so output will be:

```
filteredOffers = [{
        _id: "2"
      },
      {
        _id: "3"
      }
    ];
```

I solved this problem using 2 loops but in bad way, have someone any elegant solution, also that uses lodash?

Comment: What was the code for your solution and why do you think it's bad?

Answer (score 5):

Why would you need a library for that at all? It's doable with `.filter` and `.find` in one line :)

```js
const oldOffers = [
  {_id: "1"},
  {_id: "2"},
  {_id: "3"}
];

const activeOffers = [
  {_id: "1"},
  {_id: "5"}
];

const filtered = oldOffers.filter( obj1 => !activeOffers.find(obj2 => obj1._id===obj2._id));

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: You could have store the `activeOffers`'s `_id` in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then use `has` method of set to achieve the same result in more efficient way.

Comment: And there's no other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript) that would answer this and therefor be a valid dupe?

Comment: It seems like `Nina` has already answered what I was saying.

Comment: @Andreas I know, but basically every question is a duplicate nowadays. How are we supposed to glean some rep? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using the lodash `differenceBy` method

```js
  const oldOffers = [
  {
    _id: "1"
  },
  {
    _id: "2"
  },
  {
    _id: "3"
  }
];

const activeOffers = [
  {
    _id: "1"
  },
  {
    _id: "5"
  }
];
_.differenceBy(oldOffers, activeOffers, '_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a set of `_id` and filter the other array.

```js
const
    oldOffers = [{ _id: "1" }, { _id: "2" }, {  _id: "3" }],
    activeOffers = [{ _id: "1" }, { _id: "5" }],
    active = new Set(activeOffers.map(({ _id }) => _id));
    filtered = oldOffers.filter(({ _id }) => !active.has(_id));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Or... [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {};
var keys = Object.keys(activeOffers);

for (var key in oldOffers)
    {
    if (!keys.includes(key)) 
        {
            result[key] = oldOffers[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Also doable with Object.keys and includes in a single for loop. The above filtered oneliner looks really nice though.