# Determine if an array of objects contains any object of another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given the following two array objects:

```
let origArr = [ { value: 2, label: 'Dog' }, 
                { value: 4, label: 'Cat' },
                { value: 16, label: 'Horse' } 
              ]

let newArr = [
  { value: 2, label: 'Dog' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Bird' },
  { value: 0, label: 'Fish' }
]
```

what would be the best way to return a new array of just the value of the difference between the `origArr` and the `newArr`, that is, where `origArr` element(s) are not in `newArr` ?

In the above example, I am after a new array called `diffArr = [4,16]`

**Please note**: that all `value` values within both `origArr` and the `newArr` are unique

Not sure if there is an ***ES2016*** means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript) of [How to get the difference between two arrays of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript/21988185) and [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `some` to do the job.

```js
let origArr = [ { value: 2, label: 'Dog' }, 
                { value: 4, label: 'Cat' },
                { value: 16, label: 'Horse' } 
              ]

let newArr = [
  { value: 2, label: 'Dog' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Bird' },
  { value: 0, label: 'Fish' }
]

const res = origArr.filter(x => !newArr.some(y => y.value === x.value));

console.log(res); // assuming you want the entire filtered objects

const justValues = res.map(x => x.value); // if you want just the filtered values

console.log(justValues)
```

some - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

filter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: might as well throw in the link to the duplicate as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/55316303/13762301

Answer (score 0):

You can get all unique value from `newArr` using Set and `array#map` and then filter value which doesn't exist in the set and get all values.

```js
const origArr = [ { value: 2, label: 'Dog' }, { value: 4, label: 'Cat' }, { value: 16, label: 'Horse' } ],
      newArr = [ { value: 2, label: 'Dog' }, { value: 3, label: 'Bird' }, { value: 0, label: 'Fish' } ],
      unique = new Set(newArr.map(o => o.value)),
      difference = origArr
            .filter(({value}) => !unique.has(value))
            .map(o => o.value);
console.log(difference);
```