# Detect differences between two objects (JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a remote JSON file that contains the list of the last 100 users who logged into a service. This JSON is updated constantly and lists the users from the most recently logged in to the "least recently" logged in.

If the user who appears as number X logs back in, they get removed from their position X and put back at the very top of the JSON at position [0].

I retrieve the JSON every 5 minutes. What I'd like to do is detect the differences between the old object `oldUsers` and the new `newUsers` and store them in another object that would only contain the users who are present in `newUsers` but not in `oldUsers`. I have no real idea as to how to achieve this.

Here's the JSON structure:

```
[{
    "id":"foo09",
    "name":"John",
    "age":28
},    {
    "id":"bar171",
    "name":"Bryan",
    "age":36
},
...
]
```

Is there a rather straightforward way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Define *differences*. What output do you expect?

Comment: Straightforward? More than for each element in `newUsers` comparing with each element in `oldUsers` and if not found put in new array?

Comment: Parse both JSON >> Put `id` in array, [Diff two array in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10927963/1008278) make sure your newJson array is in 2nd array. This is very Straight forward. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own diff algorithm. [Here is one I whipped up](http://jsbin.com/limun/1/edit?js,console) in JSBin:

I will need a utility function to merge two arrays ([Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) would help here).

```
function mergeArrays(val1, val2) {
  var results = val1.splice(0);
  val2.forEach(function(val) {
    if (val1.indexOf(val) < 0) {
      results.push(val);
    }
  });
  return results;
}
```

### Diff algorithm

```
function diff(val1, val2) {
  var results  = [];
  var origKeys = Object.keys(val1);
  var newKeys  = Object.keys(val2);

  mergeArrays(origKeys, newKeys)
    .forEach(function(key) {
      if (val1[key] === val2[key]) { return; }
      var result = {
        key:   key,
        orig:  val1[key],
        'new': val2[key]
      };
      if (val1[key] == null) {
         result.type = 'add';
      } else if (val2[key] == null) {
        result.type = 'delete';
      } else {
        result.type = 'change';
      }
      results.push(result);
    });
  return results;
}
```