# Get value from .not result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code returns the 'not' of two lists arrays :

```
var original = "test1,test2,test3"

var updated = "test1,test2,test4,test5"

var originalArray  = original.split(',');

var updatedArray  = updated.split(',');

console.log(originalArray.length)
console.log(updatedArray.length)

console.log($(originalArray).not(updatedArray))
console.log($(updatedArray).not(originalArray))
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zhHfG/8/

The value of `console.log($(updatedArray).not(originalArray))` is :

```
["test4", "test5", prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[4], context: undefined, selector: ".not(test1,test2,test3)", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

How can the values "test4", "test5" be accessed ?

I could access them using array accessors [0],[1] but is there a cleaner way since the amount of returned values is variable ?

Comment: Do you want them as an array? `.get()`?

Comment: @RGraham yes, thats what I was looking for. thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/zhHfG/11/

Comment: Or `.toArray()`? But seriously, don't use jQuery for data manipulation, it's meant for the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi but how else to find the difference between two Arrays ?

Comment: By native methods (`filter` + `indexOf`) or by using a [dedicated library](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)

Comment: @Bergi but using "not" is a clean abstraction for finding the difference ?

Comment: It's using jQuery, so *no*. While jQuery might have a (mostly) clean-looking syntax, it'y as garbled as IE's DOM underneath. Just compare [clean](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-56) with [jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.not) source…

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/jquery-compare-2-arrays-return-difference