# JavaScript array comparison with JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, compare

I have this project I'm working on and I need to get all the vacant rooms from my school's timetable where I get my data from a JSON response.

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "reservations": [
      {
         "id": "19598",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:42",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T09:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "795",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "599",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2989",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "41",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A340.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A340.1"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "27832",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:42",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T09:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "52",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A450.3",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A450.3"
            },
            {
               "id": "2409",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "3401",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         ""
      },
      {
         "id": "10945",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:43",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T12:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "289",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "gorupName"
            },
            {
               "id": "2454",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "19",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A510.4",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A510.4"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "27647",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:39",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T21:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "47",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A420.6",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A420.6"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "20630",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:33",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T10:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "25",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A130.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A130.1"
            },
            {
               "id": "26",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A130.3",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A130.3"
            },
            {
               "id": "2997",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2268",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "gorupName"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "19874",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-24T06:04:37",
         "startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-24T09:45:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "28",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A140.2",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "140.2"
            },
            {
               "id": "3033",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2338",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "groupCode",
               "name": "groupname"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

The response is a lot longer but I've kept it shorter for simplicity's sake.

So I've run this JSON response through with `JSON.Parse()` and `for-loops` to get all the rooms that all currently in use in an array;

```
var rooms = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if(json.reservations[i].resources != null){
        for(var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++){
            var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];
            if(resource.type === "room"){
                if(rooms.indexOf("code"))
                    rooms.push(resource.code);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get all the rooms that are being used at the time as you can see from the response above for example;

```
"startDate": "2017-04-24T08:00:00",
"endDate": "2017-04-24T09:45:00",

"type": "room",
"code": "A340.1",
```

But the problem is that the API that I'm using doesn't contain any data for the vacant rooms at the moment so I also made an array for all the rooms in the `buildingA` which looks like this:

```
var buildingA = ['A120.3', 'A130.1', 'A130.3', 'A140.1', 'A140.2', 'A140.4', 'A250.1', 'A240.4', 'A240.2', 'A220.5', 'A220.3',
'A220.1', 'A210.2', 'A320.2', 'A320.6', 'A320.7', 'A320.8', 'A340.1', 'A340.2', 'A350.1', 'A350.3', 'A440.5', 'A450.3',
'A450.1', 'A440.4', 'A440.2', 'A420.6', 'A420.5', 'A420.4', 'A420.2', 'A510.2', 'A520.5', 'A510.4', 'A520.6', 'A520.7',
'A540.1', 'A540.2'];
```

Is there any way I could compare this array to the `var rooms = [];` array so I could print all the vacant rooms instead of the ones being in use?

As for the results I would have to see the name of the vacant room and the time  how long it stays vacant (if possible) but the main thing would be to get the room name for example;

```
A340.1 - 1 hour 45 minutes
A440.4 - 2 hours
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: You just want the get the difference in the arrays, like this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/compare-2-arrays-which-returns-difference#answer-10927963

Comment: If `rooms` also has the objects in the same manner, a quick approach will be `var diffArr = buildingA.filter(x => !(new Set(rooms)).has(x));`. This will give a set difference. But you can always loop and do the same.

Comment: the free times requires the whole time of the possible booking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could collect first the rooms which are booked and then get either completely free rooms or render free times.

```js
var data = { status: "success", reservations: [{ id: "19598", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:42", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T09:45:00", resources: [{ id: "795", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "groupName" }, { id: "599", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "groupName" }, { id: "2989", type: "realization", code: "", name: "" }, { id: "41", type: "room", code: "A340.1", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A340.1" }], description: "" }, { id: "27832", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:42", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T09:45:00", resources: [{ id: "52", type: "room", code: "A450.3", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A450.3" }, { id: "2409", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "groupName" }, { id: "3401", type: "realization", code: "", name: "" }], description: "" }, { id: "10945", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:43", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T12:00:00", resources: [{ id: "289", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "gorupName" }, { id: "2454", type: "realization", code: "", name: "" }, { id: "19", type: "room", code: "A510.4", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A510.4" }], description: "" }, { id: "27647", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:39", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T21:00:00", resources: [{ id: "47", type: "room", code: "A420.6", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A420.6" }], description: "" }, { id: "20630", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:33", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T10:45:00", resources: [{ id: "25", type: "room", code: "A130.1", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A130.1" }, { id: "26", type: "room", code: "A130.3", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "A130.3" }, { id: "2997", type: "realization", code: "", name: "" }, { id: "2268", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "gorupName" }], description: "" }, { id: "19874", subject: "subjectName", modifiedDate: "2017-04-24T06:04:37", startDate: "2017-04-24T08:00:00", endDate: "2017-04-24T09:45:00", resources: [{ id: "28", type: "room", code: "A140.2", parent: { id: "2", type: "building", code: "A", name: "buildingA" }, name: "140.2" }, { id: "3033", type: "realization", code: "", name: "" }, { id: "2338", type: "student_group", code: "groupCode", name: "groupname" }], description: "" }] },
    rooms = ['A120.3', 'A130.1', 'A130.3', 'A140.1', 'A140.2', 'A140.4', 'A250.1', 'A240.4', 'A240.2', 'A220.5', 'A220.3', 'A220.1', 'A210.2', 'A320.2', 'A320.6', 'A320.7', 'A320.8', 'A340.1', 'A340.2', 'A350.1', 'A350.3', 'A440.5', 'A450.3', 'A450.1', 'A440.4', 'A440.2', 'A420.6', 'A420.5', 'A420.4', 'A420.2', 'A510.2', 'A520.5', 'A510.4', 'A520.6', 'A520.7', 'A540.1', 'A540.2'],
    booking = Object.create(null),
    free;


data.reservations.forEach(function (reservation) {
    reservation.resources.some(function (resource) {
        if (resource.type === 'room') {
            booking[resource.code] = booking[resource.code] || [];
            booking[resource.code].push({ startDate: reservation.startDate, endDate: reservation.endDate });
            return true;
        }
    });
});

free = rooms.filter(function (a) {
    return !booking[a];
});
 
console.log(booking);
console.log(free);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have my vacant room codes now. Only thing left is to get the timestamps for them.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below helps in filtering the array.

```
var vacantRooms = buildingA.filter((x) => {return !rooms.find((y) => {return y == x})});
```