# JavaScript time comparison with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, time, compare

I'm working on a project where I need to get all the vacant classrooms for the day and basically filter out the ones being in use.

I get all the data from the school's own API with JSON response body that looks like this:

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "reservations": [
      {
         "id": "18935",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:51",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T11:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T13:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "50",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A440.5",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A440.5"
            },
            {
               "id": "2995",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2267",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "20362",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:05",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T11:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T14:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "51",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A450.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A450.1"
            },
            {
               "id": "2402",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "3064",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "20237",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:05",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T11:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T13:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "45",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A420.4",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A420.4"
            },
            {
               "id": "2433",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "3058",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "20888",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:57",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "62",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A520.5",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A520.5"
            },
            {
               "id": "3092",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2444",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "22586",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:48",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T17:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "52",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A450.3",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A450.3"
            },
            {
               "id": "3004",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2294",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "525",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "18816",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:58",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "41",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A340.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A340.1"
            },
            {
               "id": "2989",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "795",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "599",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "20431",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:56",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "40",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A320.7",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A320.7/8"
            },
            {
               "id": "2416",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2386",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "18588",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:49",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "25",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A130.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A130.1"
            },
            {
               "id": "26",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A130.3",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A130.3"
            },
            {
               "id": "2979",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "582",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },      
      {
         "id": "18940",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:53",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "2996",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2267",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2268",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "31",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A210.2",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A210.2"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "12041",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:04:53",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T14:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T17:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "2510",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "775",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "23",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A520.7",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A520.7"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "24630",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:05",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T14:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T17:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "3277",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "42",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A340.2",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A340.2"
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "27205",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:07",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T14:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T17:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "35",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A240.2",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A240.2"
            },
            {
               "id": "775",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "3384",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "25917",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:00",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T15:15:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "36",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A240.4",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A240.4"
            },
            {
               "id": "593",
               "type": "realization",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "595",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "21932",
         "subject": "subjectName",
         "modifiedDate": "2017-04-27T06:05:06",
         "startDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",
         "endDate": "2017-04-27T18:00:00",
         "resources": [
            {
               "id": "43",
               "type": "room",
               "code": "A350.1",
               "parent": {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "building",
                  "code": "A",
                  "name": "buildingA"
               },
               "name": "A350.1"
            },
            {
               "id": "2464",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "2747",
               "type": "student_group",
               "code": "",
               "name": ""
            }
         ],
         "description": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

In order to get the JSON response I need to put `startDate` (the moment user searches the vacant rooms, in this situation it is: `2017-04-27T10:55`) and `endDate` (set to end of the day, `2017-04-27T22:00`). The result for this query is the JSON response above.

The problem is that the API I'm using doesn't contain any data for the vacant rooms but only for the ones booked for certain times so I made a list of all the rooms in the building and compared it to the booked ones to filter them out:

```
var rooms = ['A120.3', 'A130.1', 'A130.3', 'A140.1', 'A140.2', 'A140.4', 'A250.1', 'A240.4', 'A240.2', 'A220.5', 'A220.3',
'A220.1', 'A210.2', 'A320.2', 'A320.6', 'A320.7', 'A320.8', 'A340.1', 'A340.2', 'A350.1', 'A350.3', 'A440.5', 'A450.3','A450.1', 
'A440.4', 'A440.2', 'A420.6', 'A420.5', 'A420.4', 'A420.2', 'A510.2', 'A520.5', 'A510.4', 'A520.6', 'A520.7','A540.1', 'A540.2'];


var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
var booking = Object.create(null);
var free;

data.reservations.forEach(function (reservation) {
    reservation.resources.some(function (resource) {
        if (resource.type === 'room') {
            booking[resource.code] = booking[resource.code] || [];
            booking[resource.code].push({ startDate: reservation.startDate, endDate: reservation.endDate });
            return true;
        }
    });
});

free = rooms.filter(function (a) {
    return !booking[a];
});

console.log(free);
```

Results:

```
A210.3
A220.5
A320.2
A520.6
A510.4
```

This only returns the ones that are not being used at all during the day but I need to get the ones that are vacant for hour or two.

For this booked class for example:

```
"startDate": "2017-04-27T13:15:00",
"endDate": "2017-04-27T16:00:00",

"type": "room",
"code": "A520.5"
```

for this I would need to print out:

```
A520.5 - 2 hours 20 minutes
```

So I need to get the room / time from the `startDate` of the search (**2017-04-27T10:55**) and compare it to the `startDate` of the booked room (**2017-04-27T13:15:00**) to get the time remaining for that room to be vacant.

**TO CLARIFY:**

I have all the data for booked rooms starting from **2017-04-27T10:55**
until **2017-04-27T22:00** as you can see from the JSON response above.

I need to somehow compare the `startDate` of the JSON query when the user 
searches for the rooms (**2017-04-27T10:55**) and compare it to the booked 
rooms `startDate` to get the time how long the room stays vacant.

This is how I'm doing my `startDate` and `endDate` for the JSON query:

```
// Timestamp needs to be formed (YYYY-MM-DDTxx:xx) in order for JSON query to work

 var todaysDate = new Date();

            function convertDate(date) {
                var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
                var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                var dd = date.getDate().toString();


                var mmChars = mm.split('');
                var ddChars = dd.split('');

                return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);
            }

            // Current time when user searches for vacant rooms
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var time = "T" + currentTime.getHours() + ":" + currentTime.getMinutes();

// variables for the JSON query
var startDate = convertDate(todaysDate) + time;
var endDate = convertDate(todaysDate) + ("T22:00");

// JSON-query
            var getRooms = {
                "startDate": startDate,
                "endDate": endDate
            };
```

Comment: it looks like a follow up of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43605904/1447675

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, it indeed is a follow up, but Im trying to do this a bit differently.

Comment: You can use `new Date()` to convert the timestamps to date objects, then grab the unix time from them with `getTime()` so that you have integers to do calculations with and compare with `Date.now()`. Calc the difference and calc it back to hours and minutes.

Comment: @Destiny_Coder_88, do you have changed your identity?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, I'm just struggling with this code. I'm working on similar to that project (timetable + vacant room app for our school).

Comment: @Destiny_Coder_88, i was just wondering.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear (for me), what data do you have and what do you like to get?