# Jquery difference between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

How i can get the difference of two arrays ?

I think need compare the index and delete the position?

The array cann have letter (example Months)

```js
// Round 1
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [10, 2, 3, 5];
//diff: 10, 2 ,3 ,5

// Round 2
var array1 = [10, 2, 3, 5];
var array2 = [10, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 11, 9];
//diff: 2, 5, 11, 9

// Round 3
var array1 = [10, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 11, 9];
var array2 = [10, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 11, 9, 1, 5, 12, 10];
//diff: 1, 5, 12, 10
```

Comment: What is that you have tried?

Comment: How much time did you put into research, because 1 search on google and you get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/compare-2-arrays-which-returns-difference

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: but i need respect the index, the old data are not update, always the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare 2 arrays which returns difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927722/compare-2-arrays-which-returns-difference)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [10, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 11, 9];
var array2 = [10, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 11, 9, 1, 5, 12, 10];

var diffArray= array2.splice(array1.length,array2.length-array1.length);
console.log(diffArray)
```

assuming array1 is subArray of array2

Comment: Thx, thats run perfect !!

Comment: @VictorMoscosoLembcke, remember it is always good to [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this question for future readers if this was useful to you, and consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if you think it is the best one for your question.